# How do you filter out all unique lines in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Is there a way to filter out all unique lines in a file via commandline tools without sorting the lines?  I'd like to essentially do this:

```
sort -u myFile
```

without the performance hit of sorting.

Comment: Asymptotically, the lower bound for duplicate removal is O(nlogn).

Comment: @gongzhitaao: Only when restricted to constant space. The use of hash tables allows you to remove duplicates in O(n) time, at the cost of O(n) space.

Comment: @chepner exactly. It does seem like it would even be possible to implement the `-u` flag in a way that causes `sort` to skip the sort by using hash tables.

Comment: Or at least do the sort last.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove duplicated lines:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

This is famous awk one-liner. there are many explanations on inet. [Here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two/) is one explanation:

> This one-liner is very idiomatic. It registers the lines seen in the
>   associative-array "a" (arrays are always associative in Awk) and at
>   the same time tests if it had seen the line before. If it had seen the
>   line before, then a[line] > 0 and !a[line] == 0. Any expression that
>   evaluates to false is a no-op, and any expression that evals to true
>   is equal to "{ print }".

Comment: Indeed, this is glorious!  Reminds me that I should get around to learning `awk`.

Comment: @hek2mgl uniq needs sort first. awk doesn't. OP wrote the requirement clearly in question `without sorting the lines`