# how to delete closely duplicate lines in vim

Tags: unix, vim, duplicates, cut

I have the following lines:

```
123 abcd 456 xyz
123 abcd 678 xyz
234 egfs 434 ert
345 fggfgf 456 455 rty
234 egfs 422 ert 33
```

So here, if the first field is same for multiple lines, they are considered duplicate. so, in the above example 123 is same in 2 lines, they are considered duplicates (though they differ in one field in the middle). Similarly, lines with 234 are duplicates.
I need to remove these duplicate lines.

Since they aren't 100% duplicates, `sort u` doesn't work. Does anyone know how i can delete these duplicate lines?

Comment: My advice is to write a "filter" program that does the filtering you want, and use that from inside vim.  You might be able to use the scripting language inside vim to do the whole thing from inside vim though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this would be a very easy task for awk, I would do it with awk. In vim, you can do:

```
% !awk '\!a[$1]++'
```

then you got:

```
123 abcd 456 xyz
234 egfs 434 ert
345 fggfgf 456 455 rty
```

if you do it in shell, you don't have to escape the `!`:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for the response. However, when I try to run the above command, it fails saying a[: Event not found. Any solution?

Comment: you do have awk installed, don't you?  That line should work, don't forget the (single) quotes `awk '...' file` copy my cmd line, and try. @user2985124

Comment: +1 This is great. Would you mind explaining a little more what this command is doing?

Comment: @MattParker you can find the explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797442/how-do-you-filter-out-all-unique-lines-in-a-file/15797528#15797528  in this answer OP wants the 1st field (`$1`) as key, so `$1` instead of `$0` was used.

Answer (score 0):

```
g/\%(^\1\>.*$\n\)\@<=\(\k\+\).*$/d
```

Comment: Where do I run this command? When I ran in vim using :g/\%(^\1>.$\n)\@<=(\k+).$/d, it says E53: Unmatched \%( E476: Invalid command.
Any pointers as to how to run this command? Thanks a lot

Comment: This isn't very helpful (especially when it doesn't run correctly). Please include at least an overview in your answer. It's more work, but will also get you upvotes and accepts.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602). It allows to specify a pattern that is ignored for the duplicate check; in your case, that would be everything after the first (space-delimited) field:

```
%DeleteDuplicateLinesIgnoring / .*/
```