# bash remove all but one duplicate matches from a file

Tags: bash, grep, duplicates

I have a large file consisting of test failures. A number of these tests have duplicate failures. I want to remove all duplicates, keeping one of each type. Here is an excerpt from the file:

```
034 [power] 34 of 343 check
056 [drive] 666 of 3345
099 [power] 53 of 4354
103 [power] 60 of 4354
231 [cpu]   2 of 653
437 [drive] 65 of 879
862 [speed] 864 of 4397 fast
```

In this example I want to remove the duplicates i.e. the additional [power] and [drive] lines

```
034 [power] 34 of 343 check
056 [drive] 666 of 3345
231 [cpu]   2 of 653
862 [speed] 864 of 4397 fast
```

I tried it using a combination of grep -m 1 and grep -v but unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

```
kent$  awk '!a[$2]++' file
034 [power] 34 of 343 check
056 [drive] 666 of 3345
231 [cpu]   2 of 653
862 [speed] 864 of 4397 fast
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfectly. Thanks. Trying to figure out how your code works. I understand the [$2] but not the rest. Do you mind explaining it?

Comment: @stevo here you may find some useful info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797442/how-do-you-filter-out-all-unique-lines-in-a-file/15797528#15797528

Comment: @jaypal Thanks for the advice. Never knew about the preferred way of saying thanks. Will definitely do that going forward. Also given that I'm still a noob my rep isn't high enough yet to vote.