# Counting occurrences of unique strings in bash without first sorting the data

Tags: bash, awk, count

I'm doing some data gathering on massive log files and I need to count the occurrences of unique strings. Generally the way this is done is with a command like:

```
zcat <file> | grep -o <filter> | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

What I'm looking to do is not pay the performance penalty of the sort after the grep. Is this possible to do without leaving bash?

Comment: Similar (unique without sorting): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797442/how-do-you-filter-out-all-unique-lines-in-a-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use awk to count the uniques and avoid `sort`:

```
zgrep -o <filter> <file> |
awk '{count[$0]++} END{for (i in count) print count[i], i}'
```

Also note you can avoid `zcat` and call `zgrep` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you don't want to leave bash: You could try it using associative arrays: You could use the input lines as key, and the count as value.  To learn about associative arrays see here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html.

But, be sure to benchmark the performance - you may nevertheless be better off using sort and uniq, or perl, or ...

Comment: Part of the motivation in not using sort is also disk space. These hosts have very little of it on the non-log drive (which is read-only). Sort blows it away for large queries because it caches it's list on disk. That said, I will be benchmarking the performance.

Answer (score 1):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) has built-in associative arrays, so you could consider one of the following approaches, which are both efficient (like awk):

```
zgrep -o <filter> <file> |
  jq -nR 'reduce inputs as $line ({}; .[$line] += 1)'
```

This would produce the results as a JSON object with the frequencies as the object's values, e.g.

```
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 1
}
```

If you want each line of output to consist of a count and value (in that order), then an appropriate jq invocation would be:

```
jq -nRr 'reduce inputs as $line ({}; .[$line] += 1)
         | to_entries[] | "\(.value) \(.key)"'
```

This would produce output like so:

```
2 a
1 b
1 c
```

The `jq` options used here are:

```
-n # for use with `inputs`
-R # "raw" input
-r # "raw" output
```