# Is there a simple way to output unique gene id's of a fasta file?

Tags: python, unique, fasta

I am working on a project using `nano` within `command-line`. I have a fasta file with over 40,000 genes and I would like to extract only the **unique** gene id's. I am using the following command:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 

    fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
    for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
      if len(myfile) > 250:
       gene_id = myfile.id
       mylist = re.match(r"H149xcV_[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+_[^\W_])_[^\W_]+", gene_id)
       print (">"+list.group(1))
```

And this is providing me with duplicates of the same gene. The output is roughly 40,000 genes. I have posted a sample:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
```

Is there a way to reformat my command so that I only receive unique gene id's:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2
```

Comment: Could you go through all the gene ids and add them to a `set()`? That should ensure uniqueness. I *think* 40,000 should be doable with that approach...

Comment: Hi @xdhmoore is there a way that I can output my results into a new file using `>` on the `command-line` and from there use `sort`|`uniq`? Or is the only way that I must do it is to go through each gene individually and add them to a `set ()`?

Comment: Funny you should mention that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797442/how-do-you-filter-out-all-unique-lines-in-a-file

Comment: It sounds to me like you could use `cat file.txt | sort -u`. Or, the linked question uses a similar approach to the `set()` idea but with awk.

Comment: @xdhmoore I knew that I could just save the output to another file then just use `sort`|`uniq` but I thought it was incorrect. So, essentially `awk '!a[$0]++' file` is that same as using `sort`|`uniq` ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The sort/uniq combo first does a sort, and then `uniq` depends on the data being sorted to find unique things. But you can actually find all the unique items without the performance cost of sorting if you store them all in memory using a set or a hash map. So the `awk` solution is theoretically faster cause it doesn't do a sort first but at the memory cost of storing everything in a big hash map. But I haven't actually measured the different speeds so in practice I couldn't say. So that's the difference. Whatever works for you.